# How do I add the With Contact information to the email that gets sent to activity assignees?

Tags: civimail, joomla, civicrm-home

In any activity that I create, I want to include the With Contact's Phone and Email address in the email that goes to the assignee. I can't do this right now and I need to enter the information manually.

Why do I need this? When I assign the activity to any person, that person might not have access to CiviCRM to look up the info. I don't want to enter the data manually. This is a serious waste of time.

An example of what I want to do is in the following diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The template to edit is the one called "Cases - Send Copy of an Activity" under Administer - CiviMail- Message templates and then click the System Workflow tab. The name is historical - it isn't just for cases.

But it seems like it's not currently possible to get the With Contact information since even the activity id is not available in the template. There is minimal data to work with.

You could do this by customizing CRM_Case_BAO_Case::sendActivityCopy() to include more information. I could see that being useful as a core improvement, to at least include the activity id and related contact ids.

Note that it's possible to have multiple With Contact's on an activity, so if there's more than one you'd need to handle that.

Comment: The information you submitted was not a solution.

I entered Create New> Individual and saved a contact information.

I'm creating an activity record for Avtivity> Phone Call for this person. When creating a record, I'm adding a person who doesn't have access to CRM in the assigned section.

The activity record I've added to the person I've added is sent by mail as in the photo. The contact information is added to the photo. What I want is to automatically fill in or select this information.

Answer (score 0):

What I want is getting the target user information in the mail template. For example :
If I do contact.phone I will get the sender phone and not the selecterd user phone.
Something like selectedUser.phone or the email.

Comment: I see. I'm going to edit your original question to make it clearer.

Comment: I have found a side road solution. I have get with Jquery the phone number and the email of the selected user (I have done this with Json and parsed ) and set it to the location field. "Location" field name is changed to " contact ". But I am afraid that the new update will remove my code :(. Is there any permanent solution that fits my problem ?